# How to use the same onActivityCreated in multiple fragments?

Tags: android

I am trying to override the key button in the beginning. I am trying to use the `onBackPressed` function, but it is not working as expected. Now I  would like to use the following function in multiple fragments. My question is, should I copy paste this code in each `fragment` or there is another way?

My code:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();

    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    Fragment fragment = null;
                    fragment = new GoogleMapFragmentController();
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you want to use one activity in different fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own Fragment class like

`MyFragment extends Fragment`

and override this function in it.

Than every `Fragment` you implement should extend `MyFragment`.

Comment: i have a problem to implement that because my fragments already extends other AsyncTask class which using a DBcontroller to "speak" with my server.

Comment: Well, that is already a question of design. I would exclude all the AsyncTasks to another class. Or you can make two levels of inheritance.

Comment: there is not other way to do that?

Comment: I don't see other way, sorry